# MapServer rendering of points takes too long

Tags: mapserver, rendering

I have MapServer configured with a Mapfile and things are mostly fine except for the fact that my shapefile has many many points in it.

This means MapServer takes a while to render the image at far zoom levels.
I tried MAXFEATURES to lessen the processing but it does not distribute the points evenly across the areas where the points should be.

Is there some other Mapfile directive that anyone can enlighten me with?

Comment: Make scale dependent layer groups. Create physical small point files with evenly distributed points to be used at far zoom or create them on the fly. For creating evenly distributed datasets taking features IDs which end with "0" or "00" tend to give a good result. Another possibility if your points have some good numeric attribute is to use sortshp utility together with maxfeatures and show only the most meaningful points like the biggest cities.

Comment: @user30184 good suggestion with making a separate file. Also the ending in 0/00 is a good idea.  Perhaps I'll try making an filter in my layer with a regular expression that takes only ids ending in 00.  Unfortunately there is no importance level to each point...it is animal gps telemetry data.  another approach is to rasterize it but I'd like to not create new files to maintain.